# Adding a node to elasticsearch cluster

Tags: elasticsearch, cluster-computing

I am using elasticsearch 2.4.1

I have a cluster of ES nodes, and another standalone node with data stored.

I want to add the standalone node to the ES cluster. when I do it, i lose all the data stored in the standalone node.

How do I add the data of the standalone node to the cluster?

Thanks

Comment: was the cluster name of the standalone node and the ES cluster same before the node joined the cluster?

Comment: No, the standalone node had no cluster name. anyway, I used elasticdump to fix this issue. Thanks